# Getting 404 Error in postman while getting response from shopify cart

Tags: postman, shopify, response, cart

Hi I am using Postman to get the response from shopify website But i can't get the responce of Cart Value. Its shows 404 Error Any solution...

Answer (score 0):

two options come to my mind:

1. you are using the wrong request type like POST/GET/PUT, ...
2. you are not logged in with the request from postman. Then you should check whats the authentification method of shopify and copy the same headers or cookies to postman

Comment: First I am using GET method to getting response from cart. 
Second I am getting other detail like product details with the same header but only cart detail is not responding. It gives error "not found" in json. But i didn't understand about logged in condition you saying..
Third I am also not getting Post Put And Del Method they are showing error...

Comment: then please provide more information. Please add the whole request you configured in postman.

Comment: I just want to get cart or User List from shopify. 
How can  i get them in postman..

Actually I am new in this...